# Radius of convergence of beta function of fine structure constant

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, asymptotics

I'm looking at the beta function of the fine structure constant $\alpha=\frac{e_R^2}{4\pi}$

\begin{equation} 
\beta(\alpha)=\mu \frac{d\alpha}{d\mu}=-2 \alpha \left[ \frac{\epsilon}{2}+ \left(\frac{\alpha}{4\pi}\right) \beta_0 +\left(\frac{\alpha}{4\pi}\right)^2 \beta_1 + \left(\frac{\alpha}{4\pi}\right)^3 \beta_2+...\right]
\end{equation}

where $\beta_{0},\beta_1,\beta_2$ are some numbers, e.g. $\beta_0=-\frac{4}{3}$.

---

The beta function of coupling constant of $\phi^4$ is
\begin{equation}
\beta(g)=-\epsilon g+3 g^2-5.67 g^3+32.55 g^4-271.6 g^5 +2848.57 g^6+...
\end{equation}
I have an impression that the radius of convergence for this one is $0$.

Since $\beta(\alpha)$ is a series expansion in terms of $\frac{\alpha}{4\pi}$, what's the radius of convergence?

Comment: If you set $\alpha = 4\pi g$ then $\beta(g)$ is also an expansion in $\frac{\alpha}{4\pi}$!

Comment: @ConnorBehan Shouldn't numerical coefficients $\beta_n$ in front of each $(\frac{\alpha}{4\pi})^n$ be different? Since we are talking about the beta functions of two different theories, I thought they could have a different radius of convergence.

Comment: Yeah, they're different beta functions but the radius of convergence is still zero.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thanks for the reply. If the radius of convergence is zero, can I still trust the fixed points I found by letting $\beta(g)=0$?

Comment: If the value of the coupling is positive and very small, then yes. This will not be the case anymore after extrapolating to $\epsilon = 1$. But there is lattice evidence that this fixed point of QED in 3 dimensions continues to exist.